# Will this strtotime code loop every two weeks?

Tags: php, strtotime

I want to display something every second week for 5 days. So this week it's  Feb 8 to Feb 12, and I want it to show again Feb 22 to Feb 26 and continue on indefinately, will this code work? thanks.

```
$StartDate = strtotime('2016-01-25');
$CurDate = date("Y-m-d");
$NextDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+2 week", $StartDate));
$EndDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+18 days", $StartDate));
while ($CurDate > $NextDate && $CurDate > $EndDate ) { 
    $NextDate = date("F j", strtotime("+2 week", strtotime($NextDate)));
    $EndDate = date("F j", strtotime("+18 days", strtotime($EndDate))); 
}

<?php if ( $CurDate >= $NextDate && $NextDate <= $EndDate ) { echo "..."; } ?>
```

I think the code is right but I'm not sure if it will loop.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you're looking for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

It is best to run your code and attempt to debug it yourself before asking for help, you never know what you'll find on your own!

As for your code, I don't see any immediate issues, however I'm not the PHP interpreter!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I did echo out $EndDate and it's giving me 2016-02-12, I'm just not sure if it will jump to 2016-02-26 on the 13th.

Comment: $CurDate > $NextDate && $CurDate > $EndDate I'm not sure if this is what you're intending but $CurDate > $EndDate should be $CurDate < $EndDate ?

Answer (score 0):

It might, but you might be better off using the `date()` function to get the current week of year:

```
if (((int) date('W')) % 2 === 0)
{
    // display message
}
```

`date('W')` will return the current week number (out of 52 weeks per year). The above code would display the message on even weeks and hide it on odd weeks. You could check for `=== 1` to display the message on odd weeks instead.